# Gradle java-ee war transitive dependency

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, gradle

My project contains 2 submodules.

- server ( plugin: war )
- api ( plugin: java )

The **server** side has dependencies:

```
compile project(':api')
providedCompile 'javax:javaee-api:7.0'
```

The **api** has:

```
compile 'javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:2.0.1'
```

The idea is that the **api** is a dependency to my **client** project which is written in JavaFX. **api** contains the rest endpoints definition - the reason why javax.rs is declared as a dependency.

The problem is, when I build my war, the war contains javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar lib which is not necessary on server. How to deal with such a situation? I don't want to have javax.ws inside my war. On the other hand, I don't want to explicitly define which libraries exclude from war and so on.

Comment: Don't you need to use `providedRuntime` and `providedCompile` configurations shipped with `war` plugin, see [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/war_plugin.html#N15D42)

Comment: @Opal You're right. I'm using providedCompile configuration in this case - bug in my question :). Although it does not solve my problem.

Comment: So maybe you should define `javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:2.0.1` in `api` module with `runtime` scope?

Comment: It is a solution, but in the **client** ( the javafx one ) i need this dependency to be compile.